# Scrapy crawls only one page

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

This is my code . Spider dont crawl urls or not extract them or something like that . If I but target url in "start urls" Then scrapy finds item, but won't crawl forward and if I but "start urls" the url that contains target list then the result is 0 . :) I hope that text is not confusing

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from testing.items import TestingItem
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name            = 'testing'
  allowed_domains = ['http://somewebsite.com']
  start_urls      = ['http://somewebsite.com/listings.php']


  def parse(self, response):
      for href in response.xpath('//h5/a/@href'):
          full_url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
          yield scrapy.Request(full_url, callback=self.parse_item)


  def parse_item(self, response):
    titles = response.xpath('//*[@class="panel-content user-info"]').extract()
    for title in titles:
      item = TestingItem()
      item["nimi"] = response.xpath('//*[@class="seller-info"]/h3/text()').extract()

      yield item
```

Comment: Try to remove the 'http://' in the allowed_domains

Comment: Nice, tanx mate  :) . Do you know what I need add to get pagination to next page ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `http://` in the `allowed_domains`.

To answer your comment, for the `pagination`, you can use `Rules`, I'll let you check the doc [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.10.3/topics/spiders.html?#crawlspider-example). It will allow you to go through the pagination easily.

Little exemple:

```
rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('xpath/to/nextpage/button',)), callback="parse", follow= True),)
```

Hope this helps.